# Two successive isometric immersions: relation between mean curvature vectors?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M_0$ be a Riemannian manifold, $M_1$ a geodesic sphere of $M_0$ and $M_2$ an isometrically immersed submanifold of $M_1$, ie:
$$ M_2 \subset M_1 \subset M_0$$

Take $X \in M_2$, and:

- $T_2$ the tangent space of $M_2$ at $X$,
- $N_{2,1}$ the normal space of $M_2$ at $X$, in the tangent space of $M_1$ at $X$,
- $N_{2,0}$ the normal space of $M_2$ at $X$,
- $N_{1,0}$ the normal space of $M_1$.

We can write: 
$$T_X M_0=T_2\oplus N_{2,0}=T_2 \oplus N_{2,1} \oplus N_{1,0}$$

Let:

- $H_{1,0}$ the mean curvature vector of the geodesic sphere $M_1$ in $M_0$:
  $H_{1,0}(u,v)\in N_{1,0}$
- $H_{2,1}$ the mean curvature vector of $M_2$ in $M_1$:
  $H_{2,1}(u,v)\in N_{2,1}$
- $H_{2,0}$ the mean    curvature vector of $M_2$ in $M_0$:
  $H_{2,0}(u,v)\in N_{2,0}$

for $u,v \in T_2$.

Would you know under which conditions the following holds: $H_{2,0}=H_{2,1} + H_{1,0}$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If $M_2$ is a line sitting inside a cylinder $M_1$ in 3-space $M-0$ then this does not work, am I wrong here?

Comment: It seems to me that the OP question can be swiched to the following more interesting (but anyway quite elementary) exercise: Assuming $\dim(M_1) > 1$. Show that if $H_{2,0} = H_{2,1} + H_{1,0}$ for all curves $M_2 \subset M_1$ then $M_1$ is a totally umbilical submanifold of $M_0$, isn't it?.

Comment: @N. Ciccoli: Many thanks for this example. Actually I am especially interested in the case where $M_1$ is a geodesic sphere of $M_0$, so I will edit my post.

Comment: @Holonomia: Many thanks for this suggestion on totally umbilical property. However, I am not completely familiar with these notions of submanifolds. Do you think that we could write a converse statement of what you suggested, i.e. something like: "if $M_1$ is ...  then $H_{2,0}=H_{2,1}+H_{1,0}$ for all curves" ? How would it hold when $M_2$ is of dimension greater that $1$? I apologize, I am absolutely not an expert in this field.

Comment: In particular, I guess I get confused with the notions of "geodesic spheres" and "extrinsic spheres", the latter being related to totally umbilical submanifolds. When $M_0$ is a flat manifold, it seems to me that these notions are the same. Am I right? What happens for a general $M_0$?

Comment: I suggest to you to read the first chapters of both or at least one of the following books:  http://www.amazon.com/Submanifolds-Isometric-Immersions-Mathematics-Lecture/dp/0914098225                                                   or                           http://www.amazon.com/Submanifolds-Holonomy-Monographs-Research-Mathematics/dp/1584883715

Comment: Many thanks again for your time and for both references. Would you suggest a free reference also?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I do not known any free reference containing exercises.